# selecting between two php pages based on a query result

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I want to select between two php pages based on a query result by using the sectr1input.php page called from the menu. During login I POST the variable -clientnum,  this is used across multiple tables.  I want to present one page (form) that is used for 'update' with the existing data for the variable - clientnum or use the other page (form) for initial input.

All of this is based on the 'key index' not NULL for the particular clientnum. The query works in MAMP but I cannot get an if() to work.  This is my direct approach at this time.  Or, should I create a decision page tat is called from the menu and redirects to one of the two pages based on the query result?

```
<?php
/**show user name*/
session_start();
if (array_key_exists("user", $_SESSION)) {
    echo "Welcome: " . $_SESSION['user'];
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
echo "<br/>"
?><br/>
<?php
/* * show client number */
session_start();
if (array_key_exists("clientnum", $_SESSION)) {
    echo "Your Client Number: " . $_SESSION['clientnum'];
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
?>

<?php


/* * select the sector 1 table data - based on client number and if the record exist */
session_start();
          $cnum = $_SESSION['clientnum'];
          $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "phpuser", "phpuserpw","telesisBWT");
          if (!$con) {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }


          $result = mysql_query("SELECT sect1_id From sctr_1_qstns Where client_num='$cnum'");
          $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            If ($row > 0)
          {
              header('Location: sectr1viewup.php');
              exit;
          }

          Else {
              header('Location: sectr1input.php');
              ;
          }



mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Aside from header, you have mixed up mysql and mysqli.

Comment: Thanks. I had it with mysql only and it didn't work either.  I'll put the query back to mysql

Comment: Try replacing `mysql_fetch_row()` with `mysql_num_rows()`. And, of course, don't keep on using `mysql_*` functions in new code.